# ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE STATEMENTS.

OK. 0 rows

OK. 0 rows

FOREIGN KEY (ProdId) REFERENCES ALLOCATION
                                *
Error at line 7:
ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns
```

Error Im getting.

Allocation is weak entity not sure how to fix any help would be nice :D

```
CREATE TABLE MANAGER (
MgrId number (3),
MFirstName varchar2(30),
MSurName varchar2(30),
PRIMARY KEY (MgrId)
);

CREATE TABLE ALLOCATION (
MgrId number (3),
ProdId number(4),
PRIMARY KEY (MgrId, ProdId),
FOREIGN KEY (MgrId) REFERENCES MANAGER,
FOREIGN KEY (ProdId) REFERENCES PRODUCT
);

CREATE TABLE QUALITYCHECK (
WeekNo number (1),
Score number (1),
MgrId number (3) NOT NULL,
ProdId number(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (WeekNo, MgrId, ProdId),
FOREIGN KEY (MgrId) REFERENCES ALLOCATION,
FOREIGN KEY (ProdId) REFERENCES ALLOCATION
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Mention the referring table's column as well, if you don't refer the Primary Key itself.

```
CREATE TABLE ALLOCATION (
  MgrId number (3),
  ProdId number(4),
  PRIMARY KEY (MgrId, ProdId),
  FOREIGN KEY (ProdId) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ProdId),
  FOREIGN KEY (MgrId) REFERENCES MANAGER(MgrId)
);
```

And always refer the parent table. Though not it is mandatory. It is just a standard to be followed.

```
CREATE TABLE QUALITYCHECK (
  WeekNo number (1),
  Score number (1),
  MgrId number (3) NOT NULL,
  ProdId number(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (WeekNo, MgrId, ProdId),
  FOREIGN KEY (MgrId) REFERENCES MANAGER(MgrId),
  FOREIGN KEY (ProdId) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ProdId)
);
```

Comment: This is recommended, but NOT REQUIRED in Oracle - and is unrelated to the error message the OP received. Not a de-merit for a rookie, but a definite de-merit for an experienced board participant like yourself. Congrats on the up-vote!   And, as I see, on the "CORRECT ANSWER" as well!

Comment: @mathguy it is much of standard. Anyway thanks for your comment. Added much info.

Comment: I don't know what "much of standard" means; in the Oracle standard, indicating the column name is OPTIONAL. And it will not raise an error. And the OP's post shows an error at the ALLOCATION table as the REFERENCED table, while your answer is about a different table. You can "thank me" or you can simply delete your answer - YOUR CHOICE. Again, congrats on the accolades!

Answer (score 0):

ProdID is one column but the Primary Key in the referenced table is TWO COLUMNS, MgrID and ProdID. You can't have a FK referencing a subset of the PK.

How to fix depends on what you want to do. For example, why do you need ProdID to reference ALLOCATION and not PRODUCT (a table you did not show, by the way)?